# Remount NAS drive with GVFS and user rights when network re-connects?

Tags: mount, gvfs, nas

I use gvfs script to mount my SAMBA share when my system starts. I run it at autostart.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 4

   wifi="'$(/sbin/iwconfig eth1 | egrep ESSID | cut -d '"' -f 2)'"

      if [ $wifi = "'deckoff'" ]; then 

 gvfs-mount smb://192.168.1.106/public

      fi
end script
```

It works great, but when network is down I have to manually re-connect. I added the same script to `/etc/network/ifup.d`, and as I expected, I am getting a warning

```
Could not change permissions for
/home/deckoff/MyBookLive/GVFS-mount
```

I suspect the reason is that the script that re-mounts at reconnect is run as sudo. So, ideally, I want a solution that runs the script every time network is connected as user. I will be happy if I get rid if the warning at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it this way:

**STEP 1**

I decided to use cifs

**STEP 2**

Added this script to `/etc/network/if-up.d`

```
#!/bin/bash

WL=$(iwconfig wlan0 | grep wlan0 | cut -d':' -f2)

if [ $WL == '"yournetworkname"' ]
then
echo "deckoff"
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.106/Public/ /media/MyBookLive -o username=user,password=pass,uid=1000,nobrl,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode

fi
```

The name and the type of the wifi (wlan0) in my case should be changed to yours. The type can be seen with the command iwconfig

**STEP 3**

```
sudo visudo
```

This command will let you mod which commands could be executed without sudo rights, by which users etc.

Add

```
deckoff ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
deckoff ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/umount
```

This will let deckoff mount and umount drives without sudo rights

Restart